# React Router Causing page redirect due to confict with site Javascript

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React.js based widget that I have embedded on a shopify website.  It works great for most sites.

For one site, the ajax-cart.js.liquid code is causing a problem with the react router and the page url changes and the page hosting the widget loads that url - causing a 404.

How can I ringfence the React App and Router functionality so that it is not broken or taken over by page js?

Here you can see it working correctly.  Click the P bottom right and click Join.
https://www.puctto.me/collections/all

Here you can see it not working. Click the P.  The url bar changes and the page navigates.
https://shoezie.com.au/

I'm loading ReactRouter like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router'
import axios from "axios";

export default class App extends React.Component {
 //app code
}
```

And then in my FooterGuest component I have used Link from react-router

```
import React from "react";
import {
  // BrowserRouter as Router,
  // Switch,
  // Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export function FooterGuest(){
  return (
    <div className="widget-footer widget-footer--login ">
      <h3 className="widget-footer-header ">
        Sign in to upload your own photo
      </h3>
      <div className="widget-footer__register-bar">
        
        <Link to="/signin" className="ui inverted button" >Sign In</Link>
        <Link to="/join" className="ui inverted button" >Join</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Did you use import {Link} from "react-router-dom"; ?

Comment: Yes.  Is that the cause somehow?

Comment: Updated with more details of that

Answer (score 2):

You could try to add this to prevent the redirect:

```
export function FooterGuest(){

 const stopPropagation = (e)=>{
        e.stopPropagation()
    }
  return (
    <div className="widget-footer widget-footer--login ">
      <h3 className="widget-footer-header ">
        Sign in to upload your own photo
      </h3>
      <div className="widget-footer__register-bar">
        
        <Link to="/signin" className="ui inverted button" onClick={stopPropagation} >Sign In</Link>
        <Link to="/join" className="ui inverted button" onClick={stopPropagation} >Join</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: ok thanks .  i thought it was something the router dealt with but is this a way to double check / enforce that  ?

Comment: Oke did it work? Yes normaly it does but i think there is some other js on the site that did overwrite it. with that stopPropagation() that code should not run.

Comment: Yes, for those two links. Ill need to add it to all the others next.  Thanks for this workaround.  I'd still like to understand whats happening and how to make sure react router is a bit more robust in these cases.

Comment: The issue is not because of react router a other scripts takes control when you click on a link i think its the page transition. I think best is that other script would be changes that it will only trigger when the link has a class or something.